# How to ignore #1406 - Data too long for column?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Using Mariadb 10.3 I get this error, while I try to modify some string in the field:

```
UPDATE article SET body = REPLACE(body, 'old string', 'shiny new string');
```

However I get this error:

```
#1406 - Data too long for column 'body' at row 242
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to ignore this error when it arrises and ask mysql to carry on repalcing in other rows.

I need this solution because I can not make the `VARCHAR` column any larger or change the type and I don't want to truncate the text in order to make room for `shiny new string`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realized that I just neede to ad `IGNORE` to the query:

```
UPDATE IGNORE article SET body = REPLACE(body, 'old string', 'shiny new string');
```

Comment: Wrong solution. It converts error to warning and truncates oversized value which may cause data damage (for example, final HTML value may become invalid). You must forbid the updating if final value is oversized. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb49b7c687187ce564da7aded5bb7be1

Comment: Using `IGNORE` works fine for me as I don't need to care about html damage. I appreciate your alternative solution though. Please answer and I'll accept that.

Comment: This is not alternative solution but the warning about a possible problem.